# Getting the background color for horizontal rule in html

Tags: html, css

I am using

```
<hr style="margin:0; padding:0; background-color: #F7D25F" />
```

However, the color is not showing in the rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `border:0` and give it a height

```
<hr style="margin:0; padding:0; background-color: #F7D25F; border: 0; height:1px;" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive about this, but I think you need to use `border-color` for an `<hr>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add color AND background-color - you also need to define the height for this to work in Opera:

```
<hr style="margin:0; padding:0; background-color: #F7D25F; color: #F7D25F; height:1px; border:none;" />
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/PMF3Z/

Answer (score 0):

only put color :

```
<hr style="margin:0; padding:0; color: #F7D25F" />
```

And border=color works to

Answer (score -1):

I find the easiest and on-hand approach is best for me is to work within the element. You can adjust the element to your liking.

```
<hr width="200" size="3" align="center" background color="#000080" >
```